# polar chart : showing yearly trend

Tags: python, r, tableau-api, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to reproduce the following chart:

[image]

But I'm not sure if's actually possible to create such a plot using Python,R or Tableau. 
Here is my first attempt using Plotly in R:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion for creating such a chart?

Comment: Why do you wrap time in a polar coordinate (with a missing legend for size)? That is just ... terrible

Comment: You can approximate it in Python using matplotlib. It will require considerable effort, however, in my opinion, especially for anyone new to that product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use R and de package [highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/)  to create a plot like this one:

[spiderweb plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIWWu.png)

the plot js code is in www/highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider

Answer (score 0):

While I was working on creating this plot with matplotlib, someone mentioned that I can create this chart using Excel! in less than 2 minutes, so I didn't complete the code but anyway as I already figure out how should I create different elements of the plot in matplotlib, I put the code here in case anyone wants to create such a thing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig1 = plt.figure()

#Adding grids
for rad in reversed(range(1,10)): #10 is maximum of ranks we need to show  

    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111,aspect = 'equal')
    ax1.add_patch(
    patches.RegularPolygon(
    (0,0), #center of the shape
    11, #number of vertices
    rad,
        fill=False,

        ls='--',
    ))
plt.xlim(xmin = -10,xmax=10)
plt.ylim(ymin = -10,ymax=10)
fig1.show()

#plotting the trend
plt.scatter(xs,ys) #xs = list of x coordinates, the same for ys

for k in range(len(xs)-1):
    x, y = [xs[k], xs[k+1]], [ys[k], ys[k+1]]

    plt.plot(x, y,color = 'b')

plt.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

[Result plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyF3I.png)

(As I said the code doesn't create the whole trends, labels,...but it's pretty much all you need to create the plot)